# Put images next to each other

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
   <div class="button">
          <a href="#">
            <img id="img1" src="icons/onas1.svg" alt="O nas[enter image description here][1]">
          </>
        <a href="#">
          <img id="img2" src="icons/kontakt1.svg" alt="kontakt">
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.button img{
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hey, how can I put these two images next to each other?

[image]

Comment: remove `position: fixed`

Comment: ..or move it to the `.button` class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```css
div a img{
  height: 10%;
  width:200px;

}
```

```html
<div class="button">
          <a href="#">
            <img id="img1" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-3N3L1JNdZ4k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/PmHzBEEHaU4/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" alt="O nas[enter image description here][1]">
          </>
        <a href="#">
          <img id="img2" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-3N3L1JNdZ4k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/PmHzBEEHaU4/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" alt="kontakt">
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```